# Ban vs Suspend (e.g. I banned a user from my site)

Tags: word-choice, idioms

Is it correct to say

> We will suspend you from our website

Or

> We will ban you from our website

Both seem acceptable, but which is the best?

Answer (score 12):

Suspend implies temporary, whereas ban implies permanent.

So I would guess you should go for whichever implication you want to give.